# Update created a conflict on multiple arrayFilters

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to increment two different arrays in a similar fashion. Without incrementing elementC, everything works fine. If I add the elementC and use the arrayFilter on it, I get the error: update created a conflict at tasks.priority. I think this has something to do with iterating over the same object, but why and how would I solve this? My code:

```
        const project = await Project.updateOne(
        {_id: req.params.project_id},
        {
            $set: {'tasks.$[elementA].priority': req.body.new_state.priority, 'tasks.$[elementA].state': req.body.new_state.state},
            $inc: {'tasks.$[elementB].priority': 1, 'tasks.$[elementC].priority': 2},
        },
        {
            arrayFilters: [
                {'elementA._id': req.params.task_id},
                {'elementB.state': req.body.old_state.state, 'elementB.priority': {$gt: req.body.old_state.priority}},
                {'elementC.state': req.body.new_state.state, 'elementC.priority': {$gt: req.body.new_state.priority}}
            ]
        }
    );
    res.json(project);
```

schema:

```
const task_schema = new mongoose.Schema({
description: {
    type: String
},
state: {
    type: String
},
priority: {
    type: Number
}
const project_schema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: {
    type: String
},
description: {
    type: String
},
non_public: {
    type: Boolean
},
tasks: [task_schema]
```

Example:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ec274b50877c671ccf9b6c7"), 
"name" : "first project", 
"description" : "lorem ipsum",
"non_public" : true, 
"tasks" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("5ec27674e0db347307902ba9"), 
                "description" : "Lorem", 
                "state" : "TODO", 
                "priority" : 0 }, 
            { "_id" : ObjectId("5ec27686e0db347307902baa"), 
                "description" : "Ipsum", 
                "state" : "TODO", 
                "priority" : 1 }, 
            { "_id" : ObjectId("5ec27686e0db347307902baa"), 
                "description" : "Dolor", 
                "state" : "TODO", 
                "priority" : 2 }, 
            { "_id" : ObjectId("5ec293db751ae07a8520a703"), 
                "description" : "Sit", 
                "state" : "DOING", 
                "priority" : 0 }, 
            { "_id" : ObjectId("5ec29591ad84927c7788116d"), 
                "description" : "Amet",
                "state" : "DONE",
                "priority" : 0 },
]}
```

Comment: Could you give some sample documents? And what is your expected output?

Comment: I have an array of tasks and each task has a priority and a state. When I move a task from one state to a different state. In the list where it gets removed, I need to update the list by decrementing all the other tasks after it. In the list where it gets added to, I need to increment all the tasks after it. So I need to loop over the same array by filter them twice depending on the state that they are in.

Comment: Provide the respective values of `req.params.task_id`, `req.body.old_state.state`, `req.body.old_state.priority`, `req.body.new_state.state`, `req.body.new_state.priority`.

Comment: the old_state.state and new_state.state is either 'TODO', 'DOING' or 'DONE'. The old_state.priority and new_state.priority is an integer. The old_state.priority being the position in the list it used to be in and new_state.priority the new position it's in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are trying to apply two different filters on the same array field and to update it. So, the Mongo engine is getting confused on which filter to apply.

**Hint:** Your `arayFilter`s have to be mutually exclusive.

Comment: So is it possible for me to do this in one query? Because I'm not sure on how to make my arrayfilter mutually exclusive.

Comment: could you provide your sample data (not the schema), and it's corresponding output, if possible we could work on that?

Comment: What do you mean by sample data? I added an explanation underneath your other comment (but im not sure if its clear)

Comment: Sample data in means few documents from your collection as it is or reduced, whichever way you feel better.

Comment: I think, filtering arrays by `_id` is best.

Comment: Are `req.body.old_state.state` and `req.body.new_state.state` or `req.body.old_state.priority` and `req.body.new_state.priority` are having same values?

Comment: Yes they have the same values. An example: A task could move from state 'TODO' priority 3 to state 'DOING' priority 1. Old_state would hold the values 'TODO' and 3 and new_state would hold the values 'DOING' and 1

Comment: I meant to ask, when you are querying, the values are same?

Comment: No the values are different but I mean the type is the same. Imagine it being like Trello where you can move a task from todo to doing or move a task in priority in the same list. So yes they are different (most of the time).

Comment: Could you post, exact query and what are the exact values you are passing while quering?

Comment: I will try the same in my local machine.

Comment: I got it to work!! It happened because I updated the same value with $inc and $set. Thank you for you time man